# Does it matter how well-timed Catwoman's jumps are?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

Most times I try to swing to somewhere, it'll require me to jump a few times to get up there. It'll also say how good my timing is on jumping. Is there any reason to try to do it well, or should I just push it as soon as possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you watch the circle for each jump, it starts big, goes smaller until another ring shows up inside it, then goes big again. If you hit it while the ring is showing she'll jump to the next spot while the ring is up, if you hit it before or after that ring, she doesn't jump until the circle has gone all the way back to full size.

Therefore if you "do it as soon as possible" it will slow you down significantly. Good and Perfect timed jumps are definitely faster.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to get the Sphinx Riddle Achievement/Trophy, one of the challenges for Catwoman requires you to complete 8 jumps in a row with the correct timing (Perfect or Good rating).

Also, I do believe that given the right timing, the jumps go quicker and are smoother in general.

Comment: It is important to note that "correct" timing does not mean every jump in that sequence has to be rated "Perfect". "Good" suffices as well.

Comment: @Kotsu Edited that in, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Have you done any testing about them going faster?

Comment: @Ullallulloo No, just felt that way. Could be I just think it's that way.

Comment: @DoozerBlake I agree, it feels like they work better (maybe the jumps are farther?) on Good and Perfect.

Comment: I find that if you time them correctly, you do scale the building faster.  Plus you are less likely to take a bullet hit, in my experience.